# keyboard layout switching with ibus

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, input-method, keyboard-event, ibus

I've had to leave `xim` behind because of various graphical issues.

And I'm trying to set up `ibus` but having trouble getting it to cycle through keyboards.

Other info:

- Debian Testing
- Awesome WM

---

This was my set up with before using `ibus`. I mapped one of my special keys on my keyboard to `ISO_Next_Group`. With the set up below I could cycle through the three keyboad layouts using my special key and compose using `PrtSc`.

#### ~/.sessionrc

```
setxkbmap -layout 'us,gr,il' -variant ',polytonic,biblical' -option ctrl:nocaps,compose:prsc
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
export GTK_IM_MODULE=xim
```

#### ~/.Xmodmap

```
keycode 147 = ISO_Next_Group NoSymbol
```

`xev` gives this when I press my key (both events occur on keydown and nothing on keyup):

```
KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x3200001,
    root 0x79b, subw 0x0, time 9147156, (-108,258), root:(763,709),
    state 0x0, keycode 147 (keysym 0xfe08, ISO_Next_Group), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x3200001,
    root 0x79b, subw 0x0, time 9147156, (-108,258), root:(763,709),
    state 0x0, keycode 147 (keysym 0xfe08, ISO_Next_Group), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

---

With `ibus`, my `~/.Xmodmap` is the same and `~/.xsessionrc` now contains:

```
setxkbmap -layout 'us,gr,il' -variant ',polytonic,biblical' -option ctrl:nocaps,compose:prsc
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
export QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
ibus-daemon -rx &
```

In `ibus-setup`, all three keyboard layouts are listed and the key to change layouts is `ISO_Next_group`, but when I press this key, rather than cycling through all three layouts, `ibus` just toggles between `us` and the most recently selected (by mouse) other layout.

Once `ibus-daemon` is loaded, I notice that the output from `xev` also changes when I press my `ISO_Next_Group` key:

```
FocusOut event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x4e00001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusOut event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x4e00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyPointer

FocusIn event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x4e00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

---

**How do I get `ibus` to cycle through all three keyboard layouts?**

---

#### Update

I switched around the hotkeys:

- `<CTRL> + ISO_Next_Group` → switch layout
- `ISO_Next_Group` → Enter emoji

This mostly seems to work.

I had to add `GLFW_IM_MODULE=ibus` for `kitty` support.